# Hide VSCode source control repositories icons

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it posible to hide these icons?

[image]

I especially need to hide icons for actions "Synchronize changes", "Commit" and "Refresh".

I tried to use configuration by [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) (section "git.*" or "scm.*") but nothing help.

Comment: "_I especially need to_" out of curiosity... why? I'm wondering if this is an XY problem.

Comment: Just right-click on them and select `Hide `.

Comment: I tried this before posting my question but this is not way. This works for tab "Source control" but not for "Source control respositories". Why I need to hide these icons? I didn´t use them for years and they take too much UI space.

Comment: There is an issue for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107145

Answer (score 0):

Since VSCode version 1.86 icons can be hidden by "right click" => "hide"